# Is it compulsory to return a JSX to make a function a React Function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Error :React Hook "useInput" is called in function "main" which is not a React function component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function useInput(initialvalue = "") {
  const [state, handleChange] = useState(initialvalue);

  const Change = e => {
    handleChange(state(e.target.value));
  };

  return [state, Change];
}

export default useInput;
```

Error :React Hook "useInput" is called in function "main" which is not a React function component

Comment: please add the code that calls the above function

Comment: I guess you are looking for `mapStateToProp` function.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are only supported in react components. To make a function component, the name of the function needs to begin with a capital letter, and it must return a `ReactElement`.

To do that, you use JSX, which is just syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement(...)`.

Comment: Not enough sleep. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

React components need to start with capital letter and also return JSX.

As you can see in your error

> Error :React Hook "useInput" is called in function "main" which is not a React function component

The error is in `main` but if you change it to `Main` (capital M), it will work if you are also returning JSX (React Components)